# Shuffle characters in the font file

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, html

I am looking for a way to simple shuffle english and cyrillic characters inside the select font. For example "R" should represent "H" and otherwise. Actually I need to shuffle all the letters. I will load this font file as the custom font in my HTML page and will implement copy-paste protection using it.

May you tell me please if there is any good tool for this goal? I don't want to use usual font editors as changing characters there is a lot of work.

Thanks!

Addition: I have a quiz game where I am showing a question for 30 sec. I need to protect this question from Googling on it. So I just need to forbid "copy-paste" and "Search this in Google". No problem if they will try to retype the question, it is senseless for this game. I am also not care about SEO.

Comment: You could likely script a solution with one of the usual font editors, but at the end of the day, it's a font editing task. So you likely need to use one of the usual font editors. FYI, 'copy-paste' protection doesn't exist on the web.

Comment: You want to edit a font without using a font editor... huh?

Comment: I am looking for a tool which can simple exchange letters without need to manually copy and paste lots of character's properties like width, height etc.

Comment: This will absolutely destroy SEO and Accessabilty and it will do nothing to protect your data. It will be like ROT13 or something: trivial to copy and paste and trivial to crack. And this ignores OCR from a screen-cap. Glyph replacement is like a back-of-cereal box puzzle.

Comment: I've added a small addition to my question to make some light on this idea.

Comment: On the Web, you could accomplish this by rendering the text into a `canvas` element. The text would be clearly legible, it's low effort on your part, and copy-pasting is prevented because the text is just a bitmap.